# Difference between for and to

Tags: difference

For and to are both confusing preposition  in English.As I know we use to with moving verbs and for with stative verb.
For example, give a pen to ayesha.
This pen is for Ayesha.
But  It's like a dream to me .Here why to come instead of for??

Comment: In many languages, the use of prepositions - especially, which to use - is one of the most arbitrary and unpredictable part of the language. You can often find partial rules, like the one you quote; but they will only take you so far. As @Edward Barnard suggests, words of perception often have a metaphorical motion **to** the perceiver. I think "For for a stative verb" is not helpful: the core meaning of _for_ is _for the benefit of_, and many uses can be seen as derived from that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a different rule regarding perception. I would say, "it looks blue to me" but "the web site works fine for me". In describing how I perceive something, a common idiom is "it looks xxxxx to me" or "it's like xxxxx to me".

Answer (score 1):

> Give a pen to ayesha. This pen is for Ayesha.

**Examples**

*This pen is for Ayesha, please give it to Emily to give to her.*

In this situation, the pen is **for use by** Ayesha. Emily will take it to Ayesha and give the pen to her.

*I cannot go to Ayesha's birthday party. Please can you give this pen to her for me.*

Here, the pen is a birthday present that I wish to give to Ayesha. I ask you to give it to Ayesha **on my behalf**.